# Java Swing Virtual Keyboard On JFrame

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe

I am trying to make a Typing Tutor like below :

[image: keyboard]
Here is the code I have written   :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
/**
 * Simple swing based typing tutor using frame
 * @author 
 * @date 
 */
public class TypingTutor extends JFrame implements KeyListener
{  
//Individual keyboard rows  
String firstRow[] = {"~","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","-","+","<<<<<"};//BackSpace
String secondRow[] = {"Tab","Q","W","E","R","T","Y","U","I","O","P","[","]","\\"};
String thirdRow[] = {"Caps","A","S","D","F","G","H","J","K","L",":","\"","Enter"};
String fourthRow[] = {"Shift","Z","X","C","V","B","N","M",",",".","?","   ^" };
String fifthRow[]={"      " ,"<" ,"\\/",">" };

//all keys without shift key press
String noShift="`1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]\\asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,./";
//special charactors on keyboard that has to be addressed duing keypress
String specialChars ="~-+[]\\;',.?";

//Jbuttons corresponting to each individual rows 
JButton first[];

JButton second[];

JButton third[];

JButton fourth[];

JButton fifth[];

//default color of the button to be repainted when key released 
Color cc = new JButton().getBackground();

/*
 * Invoked when a key has been pressed.
 * @see java.awt.event.KeyListener#keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent)
 */
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) 
{


}//end of keypressed

/**
 * Invoked when a key has been released.
 */
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt)
{

}

/*
 * Driver main method to start the application 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //launch typing tutor
    new TypingTutor().setVisible(true);
}
/*
 * No argument construtor to create frame
 */
public TypingTutor()
{
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //set non resizable 
    this.setResizable(false);
    //super.setSize(500,300);
    //set size of the content pane ie frame
    this.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000,600));
    //super.getContentPane().setSize(800,400);
    //set location for the frame 
    this.setLocation(50,50);

    //init and paint frame 
    initWidgets();
}

/**
 * Method to initialize frame component 
 */
private void initWidgets()
{
    //set the text area on top 
    JTextArea  text = new JTextArea();
    text.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,200));
    //JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(text);
    //scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 200));

   // add(typingArea, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
   // add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    //set the info label on top 
    JLabel info = new JLabel("<html>Type some text using your keyboard.The keys you press will be highlighted and text will be displayed.<br> Note : Clicking the buttons with your mouse will not perform any action. <br><br> </html>" );
    //set the bold font for info
    info.setFont(new Font("Verdana",Font.BOLD,14));

    /*set the layout and place compomnet in place and pack it */
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    /*Various panel for the layout */
    JPanel jpNorth = new JPanel();
    JPanel jpCenter = new JPanel();
    JPanel jpKeyboard = new JPanel();
    JPanel jpNote = new JPanel();
    add( jpNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add( jpNote);
    add( jpCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(jpKeyboard, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    jpNorth.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    jpNorth.add(info, BorderLayout.WEST);
    jpNorth.add(info, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    jpCenter.setLayout( new BorderLayout());
    jpCenter.add(text, BorderLayout.WEST);
    jpCenter.add(text, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //add(text,BorderLayout.WEST);
   // add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //layout for keyboard 
    jpKeyboard.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));
    //pack the components
    pack();

    /*paint first keyboard row  and add it to the keyboard*/
    first = new JButton[firstRow.length];
    //get the panel for the  row
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, firstRow.length));
    for(int i = 0; i < firstRow.length; ++i) 
    {
        JButton b= new JButton(firstRow[i]);
        b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,50));
        first[i] = b;
        p.add(first[i]);
    }
    jpKeyboard.add(p);

    /*paint second keyboard row  and add it to the keyboard*/
    second = new JButton[secondRow.length];
    //get the panel for the  row
    p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, secondRow.length));
    for(int i = 0; i < secondRow.length; ++i) 
    {
        second[i] = new JButton(secondRow[i]);
        p.add(second[i]);

    }
    jpKeyboard.add(p);

    /*paint third keyboard row  and add it to the keyboard*/

    third = new JButton[thirdRow.length];
    //get the panel for the  row
    p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, thirdRow.length));
    for(int i = 0; i < thirdRow.length; ++i)
    {
        third[i] = new JButton(thirdRow[i]);
        p.add(third[i]);
    }
    jpKeyboard.add(p);

    /*paint fourth keyboard row  and add it to the keyboard*/
    fourth = new JButton[fourthRow.length];
    //get the panel for the  row
    p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, fourthRow.length));
    for(int i = 0; i < fourthRow.length; ++i)
    {
        fourth[i] = new JButton(fourthRow[i]);
        p.add(fourth[i]);
        if(i==fourthRow.length-2)
            p.add(new JPanel());

    }
    p.add(new JPanel());
    jpKeyboard.add(p);

    //paint the fifth row
    fifth = new JButton[fifthRow.length];
    //get the panel for the  row
    p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, fifthRow.length));
    /*put empty panel for layout adjustments */
    for(int i = 0; i < 1; ++i)
    {
        JPanel  spacePanel = new JPanel();
        p.add(spacePanel);
    }
    /*draw the buttons */
    for(int i = 0; i < fifthRow.length; ++i)
    {
        if(i==1) //space bar panel
        {
            JButton b = new JButton(fifthRow[i]);
            b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,10));
            b.setBounds(10, 10, 600, 100);
            fifth[i]=b;
            //add empty panels for layout 
            p.add(new JPanel());p.add(new JPanel());p.add(new JPanel());p.add(new JPanel());p.add(new JPanel());p.add(new JPanel());p.add(new JPanel());p.add(new JPanel());
        }
        else
        {
            fifth[i]=new JButton(fifthRow[i]);
        }
        if(i==0) //first black panel
        {
             //place a black panel at first
               JPanel  spacePanel = new JPanel();
               p.add(spacePanel);
        }

        p.add(fifth[i]);

    }
    jpKeyboard.add(p);
    /*add listeners */
    getContentPane().addKeyListener(this);
    text.addKeyListener(this);
    /*add listeners to all the button */
    for(JButton b : first)
        b.addKeyListener(this); 

    for(JButton b : second)
        b.addKeyListener(this); 
    for(JButton b : third)
        b.addKeyListener(this); 

    for(JButton b : fourth)
        b.addKeyListener(this); 

    for(JButton b : fifth)
        b.addKeyListener(this); 

    } //end of initWidgets   
}//end of class
```

Above is the very simple code , but gives me the below layout:

[image]

**Problem Description** :

> For the last line in the keyboard , I had to put Empty Jpanels for
>   spacing and I am not at all able to resize the space button . It
>   should be spanned accross 3 regular buttons.  Please give  your
>   valualbe suggestion on this .

Comment: You don't expect I will read this all, do you?

Comment: I believe someone out there will definitely read.

Comment: Well, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), for better and faster answers.

Comment: Have removed unnecessary code block.

Answer (score 3):

Read about [`javax.swing.Box.Filler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.Filler.html) class, for spacing, or simply create one, by one of the static `create...` methods of `Box`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion .Any idea on how can I resize the space button ?

Answer (score 2):

this would be a ***very quick and dirty*** realization if the window isnt resizable.

but adding so many panels just to get the space isnt what i would call great coding. i would suggest if you run into more layouting problems, that you take a look at the various tutorials about LayoutManager.

```
for(int i = 0; i < fifthRow.length; ++i)
{
    if(i==0) //space bar panel
    {
        JButton b = new JButton(fifthRow[i]);
        fifth[i]=b;
        //add empty panels for layout 
        p.add(new JPanel());p.add(new JPanel());p.add(new JPanel());p.add(new JPanel());p.add(new JPanel());p.add(new JPanel());p.add(new JPanel());p.add(new JPanel());
        Container glassPane = (Container) getRootPane().getGlassPane();
        glassPane.setVisible(true);
        glassPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(getBounds().y-350, 180, 0, 20);
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHWEST;
        b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450,50));
        glassPane.add(fifth[i], gbc);
    }
    else
    {
        fifth[i]=new JButton(fifthRow[i]);
        p.add(fifth[i]);
    }
    if(i==0) //first black panel
    {
         //place a black panel at first
           JPanel  spacePanel = new JPanel();
           p.add(spacePanel);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

after a long game around swing automated look and feel such as GridBagLayout eventually i decided to write my own simple and short algorithm.

first have a look at this photo if you like the photo and that is a screenshot of the virtual keyboard then have a look at the code After the photo

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/visyboardfree/pages/main/visyboard%20free%20java%20based%20system%20wide%20onscreen%20virtual%20keyboards.png
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyCcJ.png)

I know code is a part of a program, you might have to work around to make it work but by a simple looking you might get the ide

```
private void renderButtons() {

    float 
    buttonX = 0
    ,
    buttonY = 0
    ,
    buttonHeight =
            
            (this.getContentPane().getHeight()-buttonX)
            / 
            TheMembervisyboard.items.size()
            
    ,
    buttonWidth = 
            (this.getContentPane().getWidth()-buttonY)
            /
            TheMembervisyboard.items.get(0).items.size()        
    ;

    for (TheTypeVisyBoard.Keyboard.Row TheLocalRow : TheMembervisyboard.items) {
        buttonX = 0;
        for (TheTypeVisyBoard.Keyboard.Row.Button TheLocalVisyButton : TheLocalRow.items) {
            TheTypeButton TheLocalButton = TheLocalVisyButton.getTheGUIButton();
            if (TheMemberFont == null) {
                TheMemberFont = TheLocalButton.getFont();
                TheMemberFname = TheMemberFont.getName();
            }
            if (TheMemNotAdedYet) {
                getContentPane().add(TheLocalButton);
                this.TheMemberAllButtons.add(TheLocalButton);
            }
            TheLocalButton.setBounds(buttonX, buttonY, buttonWidth * TheLocalVisyButton.getSpan(), buttonHeight);
            buttonX += (buttonWidth * TheLocalVisyButton.getSpan());
        }
        buttonY += buttonHeight;
    }
    TheMemNotAdedYet = false;
}
```